# how to view the comments and answers in superuser site?

Tags: discussion

After i posted a question, there will be either comments or answers. My current approach is to click my profile icon on the top left corner of superuser main page, under which i can see a list of my questions, and i can see how many answers I get(doesn't matter new or old). However, it is not possible to see how many new comments or 'New answers' i get. How to view that without clicking again and again each time into each and every of my questions?

Comment: When people address comments to you it does show up, if not, no it's not possible

Answer (score 4):

You will automatically be notified (via the notifications dropdown on the left side of the top bar on all Stack Exchange sites) when an answer or comment is appeared on any of your questions or answers.

You can also check a box on any question you've asked that says "Send me new responses to my posts via email".

Comment: so it will notify me no matter the comment or answer is addressed to me or not on any of my questions or answers?